# Is re-declaring queue for every message can decrease the rabbitmq performance?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Is declaring queues for every message can decrease the rabbitmq performance?

We have a scenario in which we don't know the rabbitmq queue is exist or not. So declaring a queue for every message is a good approach?. Or we should check for each message the queue is exists or not?. Any alternate good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create queue on every message. When you start your consumer,
you will create connection and channel inside it. Once you had those set up, make your `declare queue` request.

I'd suggest one queue declaration per consumer's channel.

Look at official [tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) for your language. In each, you create connection, channel, declare queue once, and start doing your work.

Note: you don't need to declare a queue if you are running a producer. Producer sends messages to an exchange, and should not be aware of any queues.